# How to read larger parquet file in Google colab using python ERROR : ValueError("engine must be one of 'pyarrow', 'fastparquet'")

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, google-colaboratory, parquet

I am trying to read larger size (40-400MB ) Parquet file in Google colab.
I am getting error it says :

`46 raise ValueError("engine must be one of 'pyarrow', 'fastparquet'")`

`ValueError: engine must be one of 'pyarrow', 'fastparquet'`

I have refer [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50760351/how-to-identify-pandas-backend-for-parquet) and run following command : I am still facing the same error
[image]

My code looks like this :
[image]

What am I missing here.

Comment: I have solved to settle this error message after adding this code
"data =  pd.read_parquet('/content/drive/My Drive/ColabNotebooks/000.snappy.parquet', engine='pyarrow')"

Answer (score 0):

First import all necessary libraries...

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import io
import sys
import math
```

We need to install pyarrow for reading the parquet file...

```
pip install pyarrow

import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
```

Now we need to mount the required file and can see the output as...

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

output_file_parquet = pq.read_table('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/ColabNotebooks/000.snappy.parque')
output = output_file_parquet.to_pandas()
output
```

**Note:** I was not able to mount to 'drive' instead 'gdrive' worked for me.